# Send JSON to Server (ASP.NET MVC4)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have JSON:

```
[{"id":1,"user_id":"8","project_id":"1","mode":3},{"id":1,"user_id":"8","project_id":"2","mode":1},{"id":1,"user_id":"8","project_id":"3","mode":1}]
```

So, I try to send it to server:

```
$.ajax({
            url : "User/Permissions_Set",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(permissions_JSON),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

On Serverside:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void Permissions_Set(List<Permission> permissions_JSON)
        {

            foreach (var permission_from_view in permissions_JSON)
            {
                var permission_from_db = db.Permissions.Where(prm => prm.project_id == permission_from_view.project_id && prm.user_id == permission_from_view.user_id).FirstOrDefault();
                permission_from_db.mode = permission_from_view.mode;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();

        }
```

But I have error near "foreach":
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I think problem with List permissions_JSON,
but my model "Permission" has properties "id", "user_id", "project_id", "mode"

Please, advice, how I can recieve JSON from client on serverside.

Update:

Now I've changed jquery, and it return successfull result.
But anyway I can't work with permissions_JSON.
So, is it possible work with permissions_JSON not like "List", but like JSON.
Could, you, please anybody advice how to recieve it, and work with it in C#...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show Permission class?

Comment: public class Permission
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int user_id { get; set; }
        public int project_id { get; set; }

       
        public int mode { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("user_id")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("project_id")]
        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }


    }

Comment: try: `data: {
   permissions_JSON: JSON.stringify(permissions_JSON)
}`

Comment: try it in reverse, send a list of items, from server thru ajax to the client javascript. Debug and see what the string looks like, may give you an idea what is wrong or missing.

Comment: hi, thanks, now error disappear, but now permissions not saved in database, and console.log(data) brings nothing, that means that ajax is not succeed

Comment: change your method return type to `JsonResult` and return some data `return Json(new
            {
                Html = "test",
            });`

Comment: it returns Object {Html: "test"} successfully. But anyway mode not changed.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Try doing it this way:

```
var bob = {permissions_JSON:[{ id: 1, user_id: 8, project_id: 1, mode: 3}]};
request.permissions_JSON = bob;

$.ajax({
    url: "Home/Permissions_Set",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json;',
    data: JSON.stringify(bob),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

create a new object. Attach the collection to that object. Make sure the collection on the object as the same name as your parameter.

Comment: hi, thanks, now error disappear, but now permissions not saved in database, and console.log(data) brings nothing, that means that ajax is not succeed

Comment: This should now work 100% with the edits I just made. NOTE: your success methods will never have data as you created a void method. Voids have no return values.